# Cambiar el color de fondo de los mensajes de la función msg en SmartDevices GX15

Tags: genexus, color

¿Cómo cambiar el color de fondo de los mensajes hechos con la función `msg("")` de *Genexus 15* para ***SmartDevices***?

Comment: A la pregunta le falta indicar lo que has buscado/investigado. Referencia [ask].

Answer (score 0):

En Android el color de los dialogs esta definido por el default del sistema.

Puedes cambiar de fondo oscuro/ texto claro a fondo claro/ texto oscuro cambiando el "Android Base Style" del objecto Main.

Poner un color arbitrario no esta build-in, tendrías que modificar el código.

Saludos,